# How can two different TThread descendants share an OnTerminate handler?

Tags: multithreading, delphi

I have an application that launches a number threads to do stuff. I have a `TThreadOnTerminate` procedure for each of the threads that accesses some thread variables to populate a grid with the results. (Each thread performs a different task but the answer is always the same, ie. Success or Fail with a `StringList` of messages.)

So I have:

```
procedure TFormMain.Thread1OnTerminate(Sender: TObject);
begin
  Result := TThread1(Sender).Result;
  AddMessagesToGrid(TThread1(Sender).Messages);
end;

procedure TFormMain.Thread2OnTerminate(Sender: TObject);
begin
  Result := TThread2(Sender).Result;
  AddMessagesToGrid(TThread2(Sender).Messages);
end;
```

My question is the following. Can I have a 'common' `OnTerminate` procedure to handle the results of all my threads, as below?

```
procedure TFormMain.Thread1OnTerminate(Sender: TObject);
begin
  Result := <Sender Thread>.Result;
  AddMessagesToGrid(<Sender Thread>.Messages);
end;
```

We currently use Delphi 2007. Soon to be upgraded (I hope) to Delphi XE.

Comment: Very short answer: Yes :-) Did you try it and encounter any problems?

Comment: One obvious problem is that `<Sender Thread>` is not valid syntax.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

Yes, no reason why you couldn't, provided all threads implement the same interface, to return the Result value and the messages.

The easiest way to do that is to make an base thread class with the result and messages and make all your current threads descendants of that base class.

```
type
  TBaseThread = class(TThread)
  protected
    function GetResult: Integer; {virtual if you want to}
    function GetMessages: TStrings; {virtual if you want to}
  public
    property Result: Integer read GetResult;
    property Messages: TStrings read GetMessages;
```

and then use it as follows:

```
procedure TFormMain.Thread1OnTerminate(Sender: TObject);
begin
  Assert(Sender is TBaseThread);
  Result := TBaseThread(Sender).Result;
  AddMessagesToGrid(TBaseThread(Sender).Messages);
end;
```

Comment: @The_Fox: Yea, I finally was faster than somebody else :-)

Comment: Thanks for the lightning quick response!! It solves some other issues I have too. Some of the threads repeat the same procedure. Ex. Ping a device to see if it is responding. I can now also include that in TBaseThread.

Comment: If you need certain functions in some threads but not others, you should probably create a hierarchy of thread classes (e.g. TThreadWithResult, TPingThread, ...) instead of just throwing everything and the kitchen sink into a single base class.

Comment: I have the same situation over here, now, It's possible that 2 or more threads finish at the same time? if so, what happens? (If all threads share the same onterminate event)

Comment: @MatheusFreitas: OnTerminate is called in the context of the main thread so the execution of the handler by different TThreads is serialized and would not be executed simultaneously.

Answer (score 1):

Sure. Add a new integer field to your `TThread`, assign it a numeric value, and then use that in the `OnTerminate`:

```
type
  TYourThread=class(Thread)
  private
    FTag: Integer;
  public
    // Usual constructor, etc.
  published
    property Tag: Integer read FTag write FTag;
  end;
```

In the code that creates the thread, set the tag value:

```
MyThread := TYourThread.Create(True);
MyThread.Tag := 1;
MyThread.OnTerminate := ThreadTerminate;
MyThread.Resume;
```

Updated: Recent versions of Delphi allow threads to be named, and also use `MyThread.Start` rather than `MyThread.Resume`.)

In the OnTerminate event hander:

```
procedure TFormMain.ThreadTerminate(Sender: TObject);
var
  TheThread: TMyThread;
begin
  TheThread := TMyThread(Sender);
  AddMessagesToGrid(TheThread);
end;
```

In the `AddMessagesToGrid` method (or `OnTerminate` for the thread, also), you can tell which thread you've got:

```
procedure TFormMain.AddMessagesToGrid(const Thread: TMyThread);
begin
  WhatEverGrid.Cells[0, Thread.Tag] := Format('Thread %d', [Thread.Tag]);
  // Do whatever with the Thread message stringlist.
end;
```

(BTW, your sample `OnTerminate` won't work as is, as a procedure doesn't have a `Result`. I suspect you want to set a different `Result` or something...)

Comment: TThread1 and TThread2 are different classes, it's not 2 of the same.

Comment: Yes, I see that Result is misleading. It should have been 'Success' or something else.

Comment: @The_Fox: You're right. I missed the "different tasks" part of the question, and just used the code provided; I misunderstood the reason for the separate OnTerminate events. Thanks for the catch.

Comment: @RBA I have the same situation over here, now, It's possible that 2 or more threads finish at the same time? if so, what happens? (If all threads share the same onterminate event)

Answer (score 0):

When you create your thread, set the `OnTerminate` method of the Thread to a procedure in the main form and then with the `Sender` object typecast it to to correct class and get the correct properties from that, like so:

```
procedure TFormMain.ThreadOnTerminate(Sender: TObject);
begin
  Result := (Sender as TMyBaseThreadClass).Result;
  AddMessagesToGrid((Sender as TMyBaseThreadClass).Messages);
end;
```

Answer (score 0):

You can adapt the code to use  InterlockedIncrement and InterlockedDecrement methods to know how many threads are. When the counter show that are no more threads, you can process your data.

Also, I saw that you have wrote a function for each thread. You can create a custom method and assign it to each thread

```
 procedure OnTerminateThrd(Sender: TObject);  

//in the create section for your thread
   yournewthread.OnTerminate := OnTerminateThrd;
```

in this way all your threads are using the same routine when the OnTerminate event is raised.

best regards,
Radu