# TThread with common OnTerminate behavior

Tags: windows, multithreading, delphi, delphi-6

I was reading this post that almost solved my problem, since nobody answered my comments I decided to make a question:

[Original Post that almost answer my question](https://stackoverflow.com/q/4875200/2087187)

As I asked there:

- Since it's possible Multiple threads share the same `OnTerminate` Event, is also possible they finish at the same time?
- If so, what happens? The call to `OnTerminate` method will be "enqueued" by the O.S? In other words, will the code be free from reentrancy, if uses `MainThread` properties?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

> It is possible Multiple threads share the same OnTerminate Event

Yes, just as the answer to [the other question](https://stackoverflow.com/q/4875200/2087187) showed you.

> and finish at the same time?

The threads may finish their work at the same time, but by default the `OnTerminate` event handler(s) will not be called at the same time.  This is because the `OnTerminate` event handler is triggered by `TThread` using an internal call to `TThread.Synchronize()`, so multiple threads triggering their `OnTerminate` events at the same time will not overlap each other.  To change that behavior (which most people do not do), you would have to override the virtual `TThread.DoTerminate()` method to manually call the `OnTerminate` event handler directly without calling `TThread.Synchronize()` first.

Comment: No, no I will not override, this behavior is fine

Comment: @MartinJames I will accept Remy's answer because he answered first and explained `synchronize` behavior, ok? your answer was very clear and helpfull too. Thank you guys for all help given, thanks @Martin by the `Application.ProcessMessages` hint

Answer (score 3):

OnTerminate is an event fired on the VCL thread, so it will have been PostMessaged or, more likely, SendMessaged.  Either way, the OnTerminates will be serialized.

That said, I have never used this event since D3, (when I found out how much of Delphi thread support actually 'worked').

Edit - you can maybe get your OnTerminate calls to reenter by calling Application.ProcessMessages within it, (if you're feeling particularly suicidal:).

Comment: Is this event bugged?

Comment: In delphi 6, as @Remy said, it uses syncrhonize instead of SendMessage

Comment: `you can maybe get your OnTerminate calls to reenter by calling Application.ProcessMessages` Truth [+1].

Comment: Well, yes and no. Let's just say that it is open to misuse.  TThread.Synchronize, (the Delphi method which wraps the OS inter-thread comms needed to make it work), has been redesigned a couple times. I usually manage to avoid TThread.OnTerminate by never explicitly terminating TThreads.

Comment: Hmmm, could you give me an example of misuse for future reference?

Comment: @MatheusFreitas yes, and TThread.Synchronize uses either SendMessage or a queued APC.

Comment: @MatheusFreitas: `TThread` has always used `Synchronize()` to call the `OnTerminate` event hander. In Delphi 5 and earlier, `Synchronize()` merely used `SendMessage()`.  In Delphi 6 (when Kylix was introduced), `Synchronize()` was re-written to use a global list of method pointers instead and then uses `PostMessage()` to "wake up" the main thread. The main thread periodically calls `CheckSynchronize()` to loop through that list, calling the pending methods.

Comment: Well, the only problem I see is if the user does not check terminated in the context of the execute, also, if one suspend and free the thread, but, as you said this is misuse, I will not do this ever. Thank you so much